# Push and pop in stack

Tags: python

This is the push and pop functions written by Codility (source: https://codility.com/media/train/5-Stacks.pdf)

```
stack = [0] * N
size = 0
def push(x):
    global size
    stack[size] = x
    size = size + 1
def pop():
    global size
    size = size - 1
    return stack[size]
```

I see that the only thing that the function pop() does is to decrement the value of size by 1, and return stack[size]. How does it actually remove the last element from the stack? I don't really see it...

Comment: It doesn't. This is strange code that uses a fixed length list with a pointer to the "last" element. (Note that push similarly doesn't append to the stack, it assigns and moves the pointer.)

Comment: "How does it actually remove the last element from the stack?" - physically, it doesn't. This kind of code would make more sense in a language with value types or manual memory management, like C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to distinguish between the stack as a concept and the list which implements it. In this implementation, the stack only consists of elements of the list whose index is less than the stack size.

When the stack size is 0, there is nothing on the stack, because there are no list indices less than 0.

After the first push, the stack size is 1, so there is exactly one list element that corresponds to a stack element: `stack[0]`.

If you then `pop` an element, the stack size is again reduced from 1 to 0, so the stack is again empty.

At no point does the size of the *list* change, only the number of list elements that are considered to represent stack elements.

You may be expecting an implementation in which there is always a one-to-one correspondence between stack elements and list elements:

```
stack = []

pop = stack.pop
push = stack.append
```

Answer (score 0):

it appears that it simply overwrites the element the next time push() is called.